# Generating an ordinal number for the day of the month

Tags: beginner, strings, datetime, objective-c

I am relatively new to programming and came across an `if` statement that I believe to be a bit verbose. I have tested my code and it appears to work without any issues, but I am wanting to know if there is a more efficient means or better shorthand of an `if` statement checking "day".

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"The date is %@", now);

double seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"It has been %f seconds since the start of 1970.", seconds);

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSLog(@"My calendar is %@", [cal calendarIdentifier]);

unsigned long day = [cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                         inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                         forDate:now];

if (day == 1 || day == 21 || day == 31) {
        NSLog(@"Today is the %lust day of the month", day);
    } else if (day == 2 || day == 22) {
        NSLog(@"Today is the %lund day of the month", day);
    } else if (day == 3 || day == 23) {
        NSLog(@"Today is the %lurd day of the month", day);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Today is the %luth day of the month", day);
    }
```

Comment: If you need to worry about internationalization (or localization, or globalization — aka I18N, L10N and G11N), then reading Wikipedia on [Ordinal Indicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) is interesting and informative.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This seems to be a more complex problem than the solutions outlined here address for localization/globalization. How are you approaching the issue in light of the article you mentioned?

Comment: @SAHM: yes, I18N is more complex indeed. I decided I don't need to worry about it, so I have an English-only variant of the code, but I know it presents problems in other languages. Being aware is what's important.

Answer (score 11):

The problem of formatting an ordinal number is a general one that applies to more than just 31 days of a month.  You also have repetition of much of the string `@"Today is the %lu?? day of the month"`.  Therefore, I suggest defining a separate function for handling this problem.  Taking inspiration from [*NSNumberFormatter and 'th' 'st' 'nd' 'rd' (ordinal) number endings*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3312935/1157100), I would write:

```
NSString* const ordinalNumberSuffix(NSUInteger num) {
    if ((num / 10) % 10 == 1) {
        return @"th";       // Special cases 11th, 12th, 13th
    } 
    switch (num % 10) {
        case 1:  return @"st";
        case 2:  return @"nd";
        case 3:  return @"rd";
        default: return @"th";
    }
}
```

Then you can call

```
NSLog(@"Today is the %lu%@ day of the month", day, ordinalNumberSuffix(day));
```

Comment: I would concatenate the day with the suffix inside that function. The caller shouldn't need to know that in English ordinal numbers are formed by adding a suffix.

Answer (score 7):

*200_success*'s function is probably the optimal approach to the problem.  We should think big picture and write a single method that will work for any number.  However, accepting a `long` argument is odd.  But I imagine he's only written it this way because you've done the equally odd thing of declaring a `long` variable.

The only thing I'd change about *200_success*'s is to make the input parameter be an `NSInteger`.

Now then, assuming we've implemented that function, here's some things I'd do with the rest of your code:

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

We can just write:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

It's identical.  This just seems a little cleaner to me.  It's a particularly good habit to get in because it eliminates a level of nesting when you're trying to nest this into something else.

Most classes from the `NS` family have something like this, and you should strive to provide the same factory method for your own classes.

---

```
double seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

The variable type that this method returns is an `NSTimeInterval`.  Technically, `NSTimeInterval` is just a `typedef` for `double`, but it's kind of important that we match the actual return type of the method.  It is not entirely impossible for Apple to change exactly what `NSTimeInterval` is.  So, we should write:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

---

```
unsigned long day = [cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                         inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                         forDate:now];
```

Much like the previous method, the return type of this method is different from what you have your variable created as.  This method returns an `NSUInteger`.

In this case, it's actually more important for us to get the return type correct.

An `unsigned long` is always a 4-byte integer in Objective-C.  Meanwhile, this method returns an `NSUInteger`, which on 32-bit operating systems is a 4-byte unsigned integer, but on 64-bit operating systems, it is a 8-byte unsigned integer.  Presumably, if and when we get something like 128-bit operating systems, `NSUInteger` might be a 16-byte unsigned integer... who knows.  But as of today, it's a 4-byter on 32-bit systems, and an 8-byter on 64-bit systems.

Now, in this specific case, it actually probably doesn't matter all too much, because we will always get a number between 1 and 31... but nonetheless, much like my first comment, this is a good habit to get into (using the correct type).  And if you're ever going to convert from an `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` to a non-system-specific-type, you should always use `long long`, `unsigned long long`, `int64_t`, or `uint64_t`.  It's better to upcast the 32-bit into the 64-bit than to downcast the other way.

Finally, if we're going to put method calls across multiple lines, it's standard to line up the colons.  XCode will do this for us... we just have to not tinker with it.

```
NSUInteger day = [cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                               forDate:now];
```

Comment: *"An unsigned long is always a 4-byte integer in Objective-C"* – This is not correct. `unsigned long` has 4 bytes on all current 32-bit iOS and OS X platforms, and 8 bytes on all current 64-bit iOS and OS X platforms (ILP32 vs LP64 model, see for example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html). So `unsigned long` actually has the same size as `NSUInteger` (even if `NSUInteger` is the correct type to use here).

Comment: Also (minor nitpicking) `[[NSDate alloc] init]` and `[NSDate date]` are not *100%* identical. The former returns a retained value and the latter an unretained value (which *may be* in the autorelease pool). With ARC, the difference is negligible (and the ARC compiler is quite clever to remove unnecessary retain/release/autorelease calls), but still, it is not the same.

Comment: `NSDate *now = NSDate.date;` even nicer

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is!

First of all, calculate `day modulo 10` and use that variable instead, from now on I'll call it `modDay`.

Then you could use an array, with the values `@[@"st", @"nd", @"rd", @"th" ]`

If `modDay` is 0, use index 3. Otherwise, because arrays are zero-index based, decrease `modDay` with 1.

If the `modDay` value is more than 3, set it to 3.

Now you have the index of the string you are looking for in the array.

Then it is something like:

```
NSLog(@"Today is the %lu%@ day of the month", day, array[modDay]);
```

I don't speak Objective-C, but conceptually, this is how it can be done.

Comment: "First of all, calculate day modulo 10" -- that goes wrong on the 11st.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yup, I got aware of that after I noticed the answer by 200_success. That answer is better than mine. I did not notice how the original code handled 11-13.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is of significant concern, this function is about twice as fast as the one offered in *200_success*'s answer.  It is based on the principle that a lookup table is usually easier than messing about with special cases.

```
NSString * const ordinalSuffix(NSInteger daynum) {
    // Lookup table using Gray code <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code>
    //
    // Normally, a lookup table with four possible values requires two bits
    // per entry.  However, since the suffixes always occur in this order:
    //     st -> nd -> rd -> th -> st
    //
    // ... we can design the lookup table such that the entries overlap.
    //     "st" =    01
    //     "nd" =   00
    //     "rd" =  10
    //     "th" = 11
    //
    // GRAYCODE is the resulting lookup table that uses just one bit per entry.

    static NSString * const suffixArray[] = @{@"nd", @"st", @"rd", @"th"};
    static const unsigned long GRAYCODE = 0b11111111001111111111111111110011;
    assert(0 <= daynum && daynum < 32);
    return suffixArray[(GRAYCODE >> daynum) & 3];
}
```

This works by using `01` to encode `st`, `00` to encode `nd`, `10` to encode `rd` and `11` to encode `th`. The two bits `01` near the end of the constant are selected by the mask when `daynum == 1`, the `00` for `2`, etc. `31st` is handled because `>>` shifts in zeros to fill spaces at the left.

Naturally, the code doesn't work for numbers greater than 31 (`>> 32` is either undefined or unspecified in C, I forget which. If it's defined in Objective-C then it probably results in 0 in which case 32 works too but no further). It does work for `0th`, since we might as well choose the last bit of the constant to make it work.

I don't recommend actually checking this code in ;-) A proper lookup table, with 31 separate string entries, would generally be easier for a translator to localize anyway. It's tedious to type, is all.

Comment: I think this answer is a really cool way of thinking outside the box. And it really isn't *that* unreadable. I see no reason to either downvote or voted to delete this answer. I like it! (Probably a good option to make it a community-wiki answer though)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: it came about on the general principle that whenever I'm writing special-case code that's annoyingly complicated, I'd rather use a lookup table. A lookup table of 31 separate strings seems... bloated, hence the trickery, but actually a 31 entry table might still be the right thing to do if written more clearly than the above. Also, a table would be easier for a translator to localize ;-)

Comment: return [@"xxstndrdthththththththththththththththththstndrdthththththththst" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(daynum*2,2)];